# Custom MariaDB warning doesn't get raised, but identical error does

Tags: sql, database, triggers, mariadb, warnings

I am attempting to create a custom warning that can be thrown by a trigger in a MariaDB database, but for some reason I can't get it to display. The relevant code (simplified and obfuscated) is as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    data VARCHAR(255),
);

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER warn_bad_cause
BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.data LIKE 'bad data')
    THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '01000' 
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'bad data';
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

When attempting to insert a value that should trigger the warning, nothing happens. E.g.,

```
> INSERT INTO my_table (data) VALUES ('bad data');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.013 sec)

> SHOW WARNINGS;
Empty set (0.000 sec)
```

But if I change the `SQLSTATE` to an error (e.g., `45000`), I get an error using the same query:

```
> INSERT INTO my_table (data) VALUES ('bad data');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.013 sec)
ERROR 1644 (45000): bad data
Error (Code 1644): bad data

> SHOW WARNINGS;
+-------+------+----------+
| Level | Code | Message  |
+-------+------+----------+
| Error | 1644 | bad data |
+-------+------+----------+
```

Things I have tried:

- `\W` to display warnings
- Checking the logs with the `sql_errlog` plugin
- Increasing the `log_warnings` level from 2 (default) all the way to 9
- Setting specific `mysql_errno` values in the trigger

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that you've hit a bug. `SIGNAL SQLSTATE` starting with `01` (warnings) raises a warning when executed in or outside a stored procedure, but not inside a trigger as shown in your example.

```
MariaDB [test]> SIGNAL SQLSTATE '01000';
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [test]> DELIMITER $$
MariaDB [test]> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p1()
    -> BEGIN
    ->   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '01000';
    -> END $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.013 sec)

MariaDB [test]> call p1()$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.000 sec)
```

I filed an issue in MariaDB's tracking system: [MDEV-31940](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-31940)

Comment: @ndiamond curious behavior of the variable `warning_count` ([MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#warning_count) and [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_warning_count)), see dbfiddle ([MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/keAEGOUx) and [MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/aTPsCJBU)).

Comment: Interesting. Somewhat nice to know this is a bug and I'm not just going crazy or have something messed up locally. Cheers!